# Converting a string array to one enumeration in C#

Tags: c#, csv, enums, enumeration

I have an enumeration with `[Flag]` attribute set on it.

```
[Flags]
public enum PageTags { IsBlog = 2, HasAnalytics = 4, AppearsInSitemap = 8 }
```

Now, from an XML file, I get a string representation of the page metadata:

```
<page ... tags="IsBlog, HasAnalytics" />
```

My question is, how can I convert that CSV string into a variable of type `PageTags`?

```
PageTags tags = XElement.Attribute("tags").Value.?;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this Enum.Parse overload:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Comment: The point is, `Enum.Parse` method also accepts a CSV string. That's cool.